# How do I correct this error after I pulled an app from github into vscode?

Tags: reactjs

I can't figure out what causes this to happen. After running this code this shows up in the terminal
Invalid regular expression: /(node_modules[\]react[\]dist[\].*|website\node_modules\.*|heapCapture\bundle.js|.*\**tests**\.*)$/: Unterminated character class

I haven't really tried doing anything

Answer (score 0):

The error you are facing is seemed to be due to the problem with regular expression. The backslash need to be escaped with .

```
/(node_modules[\\]react[\\]dist[\\].|website\\node_modules\.|heapCapture\\bundle.js|.\tests\.)$/
```

Comment: Do I need to change something in the code?